# Drag and drop GridView which allows adding items to existing items as well as reordering

Tags: android, android-listview, drag-and-drop, android-gridview

I'm writing a launcher.

It has a GridView which contains apps and folders of apps.

I want to be able to reorder the GridView... that is the easy part as the libs I looked at below provide reordering:

https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid

https://github.com/mrKlar/PagedDragDropGrid

However, I want to ALSO be able to add the item I am dragging to a folder, exactly the same way that the Google Now Launcher works. The mechanism is that after you long press an app to start the drag/drop, if you hover over another item it will allow you to add it to the folder if it is a folder or create a folder if it is an app. If you hover near the edges of an item it reorder rather than add it to the item.

I don't want to write this from scratch but have been unable to find any examples of drag and drop GridViews (or ListViews) with reordering AND addition.

Does anyone have a lib, some sample code, or a rough idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your in luck, I'm writing a launcher too!

What you can do is for all the icons, is a `setOnDragListener(new Yourclass())`

Within `Yourclass`, you can do:

```
class Yourclass implements View.OnDragListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // do nothing
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                //Code for folder

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                if (event.getAction()==DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
                    //save folder?
                }
                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                //do nothing
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Make sure `Yourclass` is in the same file as your longclicklistener

However, I wrote all the launcher code myself, so this may not work with your library.